# How to insert data from nested form to 2 tables rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, nested-forms, nested-attributes

I know this question has been asked number of times so far and I have tried figured out my solution from them but none of them worked for me.

Since I am learning rails and newbie in this open source world so its very hard for me to get this done.

Problem is: I have user form on which I have implemented the profile form as well. so when user hits sign up, email and password goes to user table while rest of the data goes to profile table with user id in it.

Here is the code for my user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  has_one :profile
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile
end
```

here is the code of profile model:

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base       
  belongs_to :user
end
```

this is my registration controller:

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

def new
    @user = User.new
    user.build_profile
end

def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)
  if @user.save
    flash[:success] = "User Created"
    redirect_to dashboard_index
  end
end

def user_params
   params.require(:user).permit(
     :email, 
     :password,
     profile_attributes: [
       [:user_id => current_user.id],
       :full_name,
       :secondary_email,
       :zip_code]
   )
end
end
```

here is my html form with nested form implemented:

```
<h2>Sign up</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => user_registration_path) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %>
    <% if @minimum_password_length %>
    <em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</em>
    <% end %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off" %>
  </div>

  <% f.fields_for :profile do |p| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= p.label :full_name %><br />
      <%= p.text_field :full_name, autocomplete: "off" %>
    </div>

<div class="field">
      <%= p.label :secondary_email %><br />
      <%= p.text_field :secondary_email, autocomplete: true %>
    </div>

<div class="field">
      <%= p.label :zip_code %><br />
      <%= p.text_field :zip_code, autocomplete: "off" %>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Sign up" %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

Now, half data goes into the table but profile is not entering into the table of profile.

p.s I have overridden default behavior of devise gem too.

**EDIT**

here are the migration files for user and profile tables:

**user:**

```
class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table(:users) do |t|
      ## Database authenticatable
      t.string :email,              null: false, default: ""
      t.string :encrypted_password, null: false, default: ""

      ## Recoverable
      t.string   :reset_password_token
      t.datetime :reset_password_sent_at

      ## Rememberable
      t.datetime :remember_created_at

      ## Trackable
      t.integer  :sign_in_count, default: 0, null: false
      t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
      t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
      t.inet     :current_sign_in_ip
      t.inet     :last_sign_in_ip

      ## Confirmable
      # t.string   :confirmation_token
      # t.datetime :confirmed_at
      # t.datetime :confirmation_sent_at
      # t.string   :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable

      ## Lockable
      # t.integer  :failed_attempts, default: 0, null: false # Only if lock strategy is :failed_attempts
      # t.string   :unlock_token # Only if unlock strategy is :email or :both
      # t.datetime :locked_at


      t.timestamps null: false
    end

    add_index :users, :email,                unique: true
    add_index :users, :reset_password_token, unique: true
    # add_index :users, :confirmation_token,   unique: true
    # add_index :users, :unlock_token,         unique: true
  end
end
```

**profile:**

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table(:profile) do |f|
      f.integer :user_id
      f.string :full_name
      f.string :secondary_email    
      f.string :site_url
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Why do we need to use `user.build_profile` in new? my other question what is the difference between `@product = Product.create(product_params)` and  `@product = Product.new(product_params)`? can you please both. @Pavan

Comment: You should be it as a different question. For now Please accept my answer and gain reputation.

Answer (score 0):

***Some notable errors:***

`user.build_profile` in your `new` action should be `@user.build_profile` and your `user_params` should look like this

```
def user_params
   params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, profile_attributes: [:user_id,:full_name,:secondary_email,:zip_code])
end
```

And you can add a `hidden_field` in your form to save `user_id` to `profiles` table.

```
<%= p.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %>
```

Comment: it says: `PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: relation "profiles" does not exist LINE 5: WHERE a.attrelid = '"profiles"'::regclass ^ : SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod), pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum WHERE a.attrelid = '"profiles"'::regclass AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped ORDER BY a.attnum`

Comment: Yes I do have profile table not profiles. without s I mean. as stated my goal is to send email and password to users table and other form data to profile table with user id.

Comment: @LearningROR You should be having **profiles** table. How is your profile migration file looks like? Please update your post with the migration file.

Comment: here is my migration file for profile: `class Profile < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table(:profile) do |f|
      f.integer :user_id
      f.string :full_name
      f.string :secondary_email    
      f.string :site_url
    end
  end
end` i have updated my question as well.

Comment: @LearningROR Change `create_table(:profile)` to `create_table(:profiles)` and do `rake db:migrate`.

Comment: No effect still same error. I have checked in pgadmin the table name is still same.

Comment: @LearningROR Delete the **profile** table from pgadmin and do `rake db:migrate`

Comment: No luck bro. May i need to restart my postgres services? still not migrating.

Comment: @LearningROR first rollback your migration and then try to migrate it

Comment: @test it says: `PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "profile" does not exist
`

Comment: @LearningROR firstly don't change the table name and place it as it was previously...then rollback and make changes in migration file and then do rake db:migrate

Comment: Pavan suggested me to delete the table and I did so: `@LearningROR Delete the profile table from pgadmin and do rake db:migrate –  Pavan 18 mins ago`

Comment: deleting table won't run your migration again...when you run your migration, entry of migration timestamp goes in schema_migrations table..so don't remove your table manually..

Comment: for now you can delete entry of your migration from schema_migrations table and then try to do rake db:migrate